# How can I transfer no generic lambda to generic lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I get lambda expression via method below:

```
  Expression IOperator.ToExpression(IVariable[] variables)
    {
        IVariable variable1 = variables[0];
        IVariable variable2 = variables[1];

        List<ParameterExpression> parameterExpressions=new List<ParameterExpression>();

        parameterExpressions.Add( variable1.GetParamerterExpression());
        parameterExpressions.Add(variable2.GetParamerterExpression());
        return Expression.Lambda(typeof(bool), Expression.AndAlso(variable1.ToExpression(), variable2.ToExpression()), parameterExpressions.ToArray());
    }
```

Now, how can I transfer the no generic lambda to generic lambda like `Expression<func<T1,T2,bool>>`

Comment: Not certain about this, but I don't think there is a easy syntactic way in current C# to have a variable number of type arguments `<T1, ... TN>`. Currently, there are several generic overloads for `Func` (from `Func<T1, TResul>` to 16 input type `Func<T1, T2, ...., T16, TResult>`). You could get away with a big switch on the size of your array `variables`,  instantiating by reflection the correct generic `Func` type

Comment: @Pac0, I rewrite the description, Expression<func<T1,T2,bool>>

Comment: I am not expert in using Expressions, so I've overseen the fact that `IVariable` is something you have defined, right ? What are the relevant parts of it to help us understand ? It would also help to know exactly what is that you want to achieve, how do you plan to use your result Expression. FYI, currently there are 3/5 close votes on your question as "Unclear what you are asking".